# I’m trying to test if my textfield contains digits I python

Tags: python

This is always returning failed, even if digits are in the textfield? Please help me explain where I’m going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
import ui
import console
import re

_digits = re.compile('\d')
def contains_digits(d):
    return bool(_digits.search(d))  

def button_pushed(sender):
    if contains_digits(textfield1):
        print(textfield1)
    else:
        print('failed')

v=ui.load_view()
print(v['textfield1'].text.isdigit)
textfield1 = str(v['textfield1'].text)

print(textfield1)
v.present('fullscreen')
```

** update ** 
The above works for me on a variable that contains a string but it's not working on the text property of a ui.textfield for some reason? I'm wondering if it has something to do with unicode?

Comment: Can you add more informations ?

Comment: your solution is correct I have tested the contain_digits with the string 'fd5151' it returned True for me. just double check your configuration.

Comment: The above works for me on a variable that contains a string but it's not working on the text property of a ui.textfield for some reason? I'm wondering if it has something to do with unicode?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function for `contains_digit`:

```
def contains_digits(d):
    for char in d:
        if char.isdigit():
            return True
    return False
```

Also as stated by Van Peer, `print(v['textfield1'].text.isdigit)` should be `print(v['textfield1'].text.isdigit())`, but it would only print True if every single character in the text is a digit.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Following function will return `True` if a digit exists in the string otherwise `False`.

```
def contains_digits(s):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in s)
```

Comment: I get failed still - even if there are digits. The console reads <built-in method is digit of str object at 0x109029ab0>